# Getting null pointer exception in a simple vertx router implementation

Tags: java, vert.x

I learning the [Vert.x](https://vertx.io/) framework in Java. I am trying to create a simple API using `Router` and `Vert.x web`. Below is my code:

My Main Class - `MainVerticle.java` (Verticle):

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle{

    final int VA_PORT = 7535;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        // URL routers
        IController controller = new RequestController();

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.post("/vassist").handler(
                routingContext -> controller.opController(routingContext) 
        );

        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(VA_PORT, asyncResult -> {

            if(asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                LOGGER.info("Verticle deployed successfully. Listening on port: " + VA_PORT);
            }
            else {
                LOGGER.error("Could not start a HTTP server", asyncResult.cause());
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        // Deploy main verticle
        vertx.deployVerticle(new MainVerticle());
    }

}
```

Interface - `IController.java`:

```
public interface IController {
    public void opController(RoutingContext routingContext);
}
```

`RequestController.java` implementing the above interface:

```
public class RequestController implements IController {

    @Override
    public void opController(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        JsonObject jso = routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
        System.out.println("Received json body as : " + jso.encodePrettily());
    }

}
```

The above code successfully deploys the verticle and creates an http server, however, whenever, I send an HTTP POST with a sample `json` body, I am getting null pointer exception at `System.out.println("Received json body as : " + jso.encodePrettily());` of `RequestController.java`.

Is my implementation of HttpServer not correct? Please note that I don't want to write the http request handler as an anonymous function inside `creatHttpServer()` method of `vertx`.

Comment: seems like .getBodyAsJson() is failing to instantiate jso which causes it to be null when println tries to print it. Not 100% sure what's causing it.

Comment: @Patrick Fixed now. Thanks for your input and taking the time to review my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is fixed now. Problem was I didn't impletement the bodyhandler for the received request in opController method. Correct implementation is as follows:

```
public void opController(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        routingContext.request().bodyHandler(bodyHandler -> {
            JsonObject jso = bodyHandler.toJsonObject();
            System.out.println("Received json body as : " + jso.encodePrettily());
        });

        // Complete request
        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(200).end("Done!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by defining **once** a BodyHandler and get the body as buffer, string, json or json array like bellow:

```java
public class HttpServer extends AbstractVerticle {

   @Override
   public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
      var router = Router.router(vertx);
      //notice here
      router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

      // a bonus :) 
      router.route().handler(LoggerHandler.create(LoggerFormat.DEFAULT));

      router.post("/api/books").handler(this::getAllBooks);

      vertx.createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(router)
            .listen(config().getInteger("server.port", 9000), lh -> startFuture.complete());
   }


   private void getAllBooks(RoutingContext rc) {
      // do something with the body
      JsonObject jso = rc.getBodyAsJson(); // or String body = getBodyAsString();
      System.out.println("Received json body as : " + jso.encodePrettily());
      //respond
      rc.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.OK.code()).end("Done!");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertx HttpServer will capture all exceptions which happen in routing Handlers then return http response with status-code = 500 (=" Internal Server Error"). So http server will not be stopped by any exception.

use "try catch" to capture exceptions, for example:

```
String abc = null;
try {
    // add your code here
    abc.charAt(0);  
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

other way to handler exceptions:

```
router.route("/*").failureHandler(rc->{
    int statusCode = rc.statusCode();
    System.out.println("status code = " + statusCode );
    
    rc.response().setStatusCode(statusCode).end("failureHandler here");  
});
```